# jQuery Mouseover DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, mouseover

I have a number of elements (the total number of which I do not know). I want something to appear when I mouse-over any one of these elements (which is taken care of by having a `mouseover` bound to the shared class of these elements).

However, the thing that I want to appear on `mouseover` is dependent on what the cursor is over - so I need to get the DOM element under the cursor, without the luxury of being able to bind `mouseover` events to each element in code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you paste some HTML ? examples of DOM element selectors can't be done without knowing how you have your HTML structured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*HTML:*

```
<a id="say1" class="say" href="#" data-word="one">Say 'one'</a>
<a id="say2" class="say" href="#" data-word="two">Say 'two'</a>
<a id="say3" class="say" href="#" data-word="three">Say 'three'</a>
```

*Javascript (with jQuery):*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.say').mouseover(function () {
    alert($(this).data('word'));
  });
});
```

*Pure Javascript (without jQuery, it is not equivalent):*

```
window.onload = function () {
  var onmouseover = function (e) {
    alert(e.target.getAttribute('data-word'));
  };

  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('say');   

  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
    elems[i].onmouseover = onmouseover;
  }
};
```

Instead of calling `alert` function you may implement any logic.

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation is your friend here.

See this post from Christian Heilmann on that topic http://www.icant.co.uk/sandbox/eventdelegation/.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery makes this easy with `.each()`:

```
$('#container').bind('mouseover', function () {
        $(".selector").each(function(){
                // Do something $(this) = item clicked
                $(this).toggleClass('.example'); // Toggle class is just an example
        });
});
```

You can then check certain characteristics of $(this) and then do different things based on the values/characteristics.